# Embed matplotlib bar graph in html page

Tags: html, django, matplotlib, embed

I am trying to embed a matplotlib bar graph in html page. I have tried almost everything. here's my code-

views.py-

```
def result(request)
    plt.bar(x,h)
    plt.xlabel("Personality")
    plt.ylabel("course")
    plt.show()
return render(request,'result.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

You using **plt.show()** which used to display figure.
If you want to show this on HTML you can save the image by using **plt.savefig('my_plot.png')**
and get the image path on the template.

```
   def result(request)
        plt.bar(x,h)
        plt.xlabel("Personality")
        plt.ylabel("course")
        plt.savefig('my_plot.png')
    
        return render(request,'result.html')
```

result.html

```
<img src='my_plot.png'>
```

Comment: It said "failed to load local resource"

Answer (score 1):

I got the image in html page.
Code-

```
views.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import base64
def result(request):
            plt.bar(x,h)
            plt.xlabel("Personality")
            plt.ylabel("Scale")
            axes = plt. gca()
            axes. xaxis. label. set_size(15)
            axes. yaxis. label. set_size(15)
            buf = BytesIO()
            plt.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=300)
            image_base64 = base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
            buf.close()
            return render(request,'result.html',{"image_base64":image_base64})

result.html-
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image_base64}}" alt="some text to display to your users when the image does not show correctly" width=500 height=auto />
```